# git remove branch without removing commits

Tags: git

I have two branches I normally work on: master and homepage_buildout. I was recently told to checkout an old commit from before I was working on the project. I simply did:

```
 git checkout [commit number]
```

Then I decided to make this old commit a branch like so:

```
 git checkout -b old_homepage
```

Now, I realized that I don't need to be able to reference the branch `old_homepage` anymore, but I still want it exist as a commit. How do I retain those commits but remove the branch from appearing when I type:

```
 git branch
```

Comment: You mean you want to merge your commits on the branch that you want to delete with master?

Comment: assuming the commit is an ancestor of `master` (or any other branch) the commit won't go away as long as the branch isn't changed in a non-fast-forward manner.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I *think* what you're actually asking boils down to: "if I do `git branch -d old_homepage` will the commits get lost", and the answer is: "Deleting the name only deletes the *name*; the commits themselves stick around as long as you can see them in `git log --all`, and actually even longer."

To visualize this better, run something like `gitk --all` or `gitk --tags` (try both on some complex git repos).  Scroll around through the commits.  Now imagine putting a sticky note on any commit.  That's a "tag" or "branch" name.  Take the sticky note off.  Commit is still there, right? :-)

That leaves one obvious question: when do things like commits *actually* go away?  The answer is: only after you remove *all* the names that lead to them.  The `gitk` command (like most other git commands) starts with the name `HEAD`.  If you give it `--all` it adds all the branch names it can find.  If you give it `--tags` it adds all the tag names it can find.  Then it works backwards, looking at each commit to see what other commit(s) it refers to.

Git removes things (commits, etc) when there is no way to find them by starting at one of these obvious names and working backwards.  (Even then it waits a long time, 30 to 90 days by default.)  So, if you add a branch or tag label to an old commit whose number you found by doing `git log` for instance, that gives you a new obvious name for that commit number; but removing again it is safe as long as it's not the *only* way to find it by name.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  If the old commit is in some branch's history, it won't go away.  You can tag it if you like for easier access, but it's not necessary for retention purposes.  As long as you don't rewrite the branch's history in a way that causes that commit to become orphaned (and you'd likely have to be trying to do that for it to happen), the commit will be around as long as there's some branch which has it in its history.

Comment: Thanks, torek! That was exactly my question.

Answer (score 3):

You can tag the the commit:

```
$ git tag <tagname> <commit-hash>
```

Since a tag references the commit, it won't get garbage-collected.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not quite sure but in that situation you would usually use a tag.

```
git tag <some-name> <commit-id>
```

It would not show up in `git-branch` but `git-tag` will show it.